# Finding plane which cuts prism in a section which forms an equilateral triangle

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

We are given a rectangular prism having $x+y=0,x-y=0$ and $x=1$ as its faces. We have to find the normal vector to the plane which cuts this prism in a section that forms an equilateral triangle.

Now I couldn't visualize it properly so I used a 3-D calculator:
https://www.geogebra.org/3d/trapevzc

Using this I could see that $(\sqrt2,0,1)$ is one possible normal vector but how can I prove it mathematically? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HINT. A possible equilateral section has vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,1,\sqrt2)$, $(1,-1,\sqrt2)$.